# How serialize a form in to a div

Tags: jquery, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a form into a div but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

I have this:

```
<div id="dialog-form">
   <form>

<LABEL for="firstname">First name: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" id="firstname"><BR>
<LABEL for="lastname">Last name: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" id="lastname"><BR>
<LABEL for="email">email: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" id="email"><BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Male"> Male<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"> Female<BR>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">

    </form>
</div>
```

I try this :

```
jQuery("#dialog-form").find("form").serialize()
```

but it returns an empty string, even if the text fields contain data. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: What do you expect?  I don't see any form elements here.

Comment: What do you mean it "dont work"? Serialize an empty form, and you'll get an empty array. This is correct behaviour.

Comment: this only one example obviously I have elements

Comment: This is not obvious, a we don't take something so fundamental for granted. We also need more to go on than "it doesn't work". *What* doesn't work? What does it do, raise an exception, return an empty array, reboot your computer, *what*? What do you *expect* it to do? How does what it's doing differ from your expectations?

Comment: ok ... but we return to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no `name` attributes on your `<input>` elements. Serialize (and indeed, regular HTTP form submissions) require that your input elements be named, as the entire purpose of `serialize` is to turn your elements into `name=value` pairs.

Add `name="..."` attributes to your `<input>` tags:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
```

Your radio buttons will also be omitted form the serialize string if they're not checked.